# Best way to differentiate between signals for a command-line Ruby script

Tags: ruby, exception, signals, interrupt

I have a command-line Ruby script where I need to differentiate between different [SignalException](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/SignalException.html)s. Specifically I want to catch and ignore control+c (`SIGINT`) and exit from the script when it receives a control+\ (`SIGQUIT`).

I'm still relatively new to Ruby and would like to know the best (or canonical) way to achieve my goal. I'm also wondering if there is the possibility of running into OS differences (I'm currently running on OS X but would my solution work on Windows, Linux, etc.?)

I was able to obtain the list of possible signals in two different ways:

1. from bash: `stty -a` (this is nice because it displays the control key combos)
2. via IRB: `Signal.list`

Here is how I am playing around with this stuff:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

while true

  begin

    puts "Spinning my wheels..."
    loop {}

  rescue Interrupt => e

    puts "\nCaught ^C - ignoring"

  rescue SignalException => e

    puts "\nCaught #{e.inspect}"

    if e.message == "SIGQUIT"
      puts "Shutting down..."
      exit
    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to capture signals is with [`Signal.trap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Signal.html):

```
Signal.trap('QUIT') do
  puts "Shutting down..."
  exit
end

Signal.trap('INT', 'IGNORE')
```

The linked docs have some comments on OS differences, specifically:

> The list of available signal names and their interpretation is system dependent. Signal delivery semantics may also vary between systems; in particular signal delivery may not always be reliable.

Comment: Thanks! That is how I started out but changed over to rescue semantics thinking that it was easier to read. I'll definitely change it back.